# how can i change an ImageView with a runOnUiThread

Tags: android

I m trying to change the imageview everytime that a sound get finish so I ussed a runOnUIThread but the image just shows me the last image when the loop while that I put to change the images finish and below the code.

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends ClassePai {

MediaPlayer avemarias,misterios;
ImageView imagem ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    avemarias = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.teste);

    imagem = (ImageView) findViewById(id.imageViewGoz);



    while(contador<3){

        mudaImagem(imagem,avemarias,misterios);

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_principal, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

```
public class ClassePai extends Activity {
protected static int contador = 0;

protected void mudaImagem(final ImageView imagem,
        final MediaPlayer avemaria, final MediaPlayer misterios) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


                if(contador >= 0){

                    avemaria.start();
                }else if (contador == 11){

                    misterios.start();
                }else if (contador == 21){
                    misterios.start();
                }



                if (avemaria.isPlaying()||misterios.isPlaying()) {

                    imagem.setImageResource(com.willamydotcom.osantoterco.R.drawable.goz_quar+contador);



                while (avemaria.isPlaying()) {

                }
                    contador++;


                }


        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code it's hard to know where to start. You should not be looping inside onCreate(); the Activity methods are called from the UI thread so you don't need to use runOnUiThread() - it is for use when a separate thread wants to update the ui - if you want to schedule things to happen in the future there are other ways of doing that; why is contador declared static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work:

```
imagem.setImageResource(
        com.willamydotcom.osantoterco.R.drawable.goz_quar + contador);
```

You're attempting to change the ImageView's image resource, but you're confusing the resource name with what in your code is actually the resource's ID.

Look at your Logcat: Android can't find those resources and you're likely getting a crash with a stack trace.

You will have to write a switch statement to handle this correctly:

```
switch(contador) {
case 0:
    imagem.setImageResource(
            com.willamydotcom.osantoterco.R.drawable.goz_quar0);
    break;
case 1:
    imagem.setImageResource(
            com.willamydotcom.osantoterco.R.drawable.goz_quar1);
    break;
case 2:
    imagem.setImageResource(
            com.willamydotcom.osantoterco.R.drawable.goz_quar2);
    break;
}
```

There are other problems with your code: executing `mudaImagem()` from the `onCreate()`, only then to execute `runOnUiThread()` has no purpose.